# .Max() method giving error when used in an if else

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

My application is in **Asp.Net** coded in **C#** and i'm using **LINQ** for database transactions. My requirement is to get the Max value of the records saved in a certain table, for this i'm using **Max()** method.

**Below is my controller code :**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Entity_Name Entity_Object)
    {
          if (Entity_Object.Condition == true)
          {
                    My required code
          }
          else
          {
                var get_Max_Number = db.Entity_Name.ToList();
                long Max_Number = 0;

                if (get_Max_Number.Count() > 0)
                {
                    Max_Number = Convert.ToInt64(get_Max_Number.Max());

                }
                    My required code
           }
    }
```

My issue is when i remove the If-else condition then the same **Max()** method query works perfect, but when i add the If-else statement then i gets the following error.

**Error:**

**At least one object must implement IComparable.**

**What i tried :**

1. I attempted to remove the If-Else
2. I placed the Max() method logic above the If-else

**Placing the Max() method above If-Else**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Entity_Name Entity_Object)
{
      var get_Max_Number = db.Entity_Name.ToList();
      long Max_Number = 0;

      if (get_Max_Number.Count() > 0)
      {
             Max_Number = Convert.ToInt64(get_Max_Number.Max());
      }
      if (Entity_Object.Condition == true)
      {
             My required code
      }
      else
      {
             My required code
      }
}
```

Comment: Use get_Max_Number.Max(x => x.ID) instead of get_Max_Number.Max(). Since get_Max_Number is a list

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi, but why is this happening only when i'm using the If-else statement, if i remove the If-Else from my code then i don't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Max()` needs to know what you're getting the maximum of. If you're `Entity_Name` class contains a number of properties (strings, ints etc...) then you need to tell it what to get the Maximum on the basis of.

Another thing, you're connecting to a DB via Linq from the looks of things, but executing your Count() & Max() functions in memory after you've retrieved the entire contents of the database table. This will be very inefficient as the table grows in size. LinqToSql & LinqToEF support pushing those functions down to the database level. I'd recommend changing your code to the following.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Entity_Name Entity_Object)
{
      if (Entity_Object.Condition == true)
      {
          //My required code
      }
      else
      {
            long Max_Number = 0;
            if(db.Entity_Name.Count() > 0)
            {
                Max_Number = Convert.ToInt64(
                                db.Entity_Name.Max(x => x.PropertyToGetMaxOf)
                             );
            }
            //My required code
       }
}
```